# Looking for declarative approach to updating a field on a child record basd on a value from the parent record

Tags: custom-object, field-update, roll-up-summary

I am racking my brain on the best way to solve for this seemingly easy issue.

First let me set the stage a bit:
I have custom objects called 'Demand' and 'Release'.  Each demand is associated to a release by a Release ID that it finds via lookup to the release object.

Now for what I need to accomplish:
There is a field on the Demand record called Total Estimated Work.  I have a custom field on the Release record called Total Estimated Work that I need to populate with the sum of the field from the demand.  The trick is that there could be multiple demands associated to each release so I would need the sum of all values where release ID is populated on a demand.

I have the Demand related list on the Release page layout, but I cannot create a Roll-Up Summary field because Release is not the Master object.  Any other ideas to make this as simple and useful as possible?

Hopefully all this makes sense and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 choices, one, switch it to Master/Detail and then use a roll up summary field or create a trigger to emulate the roll up summary field.  The trigger would be on the demand object and every time there was a DML (insert, update or delete) the total would need to get recalculated for the parent release record.

Comment: I was afraid that a trigger was the answer.  Thank you JimRae for the confirmation!